# Date Format in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date

This Script date.format.js in http://stevenlevithan.com/assets/misc/date.format.js

```
 var txt = 04/04;<br/>
 dateFormat(txt, “dd/mm/yyyy”);
```

**result** : 04/04/2001
**I Want Result** : 04/04/2013

Comment: Could you please explain what you are trying to do, what is the output and what you would expect to have?

Comment: it is browser depended, Chrome converts `new Date('04/04')` to `Wed Apr 04 2001 00:00:00`, while FF gives `Invalid Date`

Answer (score 3):

You are feeding the function an ambiguous date, don't expect a neat result.

In Firefox, I get "01/01/1970", but if I wrap 04/04 in quotes, so I believe what you I get invalid date, check the js file in line 38 to see why.

What you can do is add the current year pro grammatically like this http://jsfiddle.net/nabil_kadimi/c3Nsf/2/:

```
var txt = '04/04';
txt += '/' + (new Date()).getFullYear();
window.alert(dateFormat(txt, "dd/mm/yyyy"));
```

Comment: How if var txt = '04/04 23:03:00';

Comment: Do you mean that you don't knw how txt will be formatted in advance?

Answer (score 0):

You would want to read [this](http://blog.dygraphs.com/2012/03/javascript-and-dates-what-mess.html) wonderful article on date parsing idiosyncrasies between various browsers.

There are some rules of the thumb provided for working with dates and also about how Chrome is a more accepting browser than others in terms of date formats.